# grails eclipse - Unknown tag(r:require)

Tags: eclipse, grails, sitemesh

**Why do I see this** `Unknown tag(r:require)` **warning in eclipse in one of my project?**

[image: Unknown tag(r:require)]

`r:require` => tells which resource modules the current GSP requires ([Optimising your Application with Grails Resources Plugin](http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2011/09/12/optimising-your-application-with-grails-resources-plugin/), Mark Palmer)

**While the other project I am working has no such warnings.**

[image: No r:require warning]

Comment: You might need the [eclipse settings plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/eclipse-scripts) for your app.

Comment: I have already eclipsified it with `grails integrate-with --eclipse`